# WitAI - Your app may fail to handle this story properly

Tags: artificial-intelligence, wit.ai

I've been playing with WitAI recently to see what it can do, and I had built a user flow of about 5/6 questions, with a couple of Yes/No/I don't know branches etc. I've set up a couple of "bot executes" options with the hope in the future that I will write some function on my side to do data processing etc.

But on every save now, I see a red light on the left side saying "Your app may fail to handle this story properly".

[image: WitAI Warning Message]

I've rebuilt a use flow with no bot executes, and no branches, and I've trained up the bot on each sentence to expect, but I still see this. I'm really confused, as there are no fields highlighted red to suggest that the bot doesn't understand that line. Can anyone help out here?

Comment: Give it more training data. The double check if you are using Trait or String search.

The other option is to switch to Api.ai. Which I did and I've not looked back.